Risk of crash due to schema changes in PuTTY settings
Due to different reasons we are forced to deploy two different putty executables on the same system, whose version might be out of sync. As both executables seem to store their settings in the same windows registry path, the concern arose, that the newer of the two versions might write settings in a different schema, that the older version can no longer process. This could in the worst case even lead to the older version being no longer able to start.
Is anyone aware if something like this happened in the past? How backwards compatible are changes in the settings schema in general?
I tried a search in the putty documentation, but couldn't find anything regarding this issue.

First question is if both versions store sessions at all. The other settings I see are Jumplist and SShHostkeys, both with a very simple scheme that doesn't seem to change very often. BTW. what versions are you talking about or better how many years and Putty versions have passed between the two versions?

With the one that can be newer, users have complete freedom, so they would also have the option to store sessions. Currently there is version 0.81, which is the newest one and version 0.77 (released 2022-05-27).
In general updating of both is possible, but the one, that is behind comes with much more overhead and therefore gets updated less frequently.

The schema should be compatible. You cannot store the sessions ina file with default putty. If concerned, you’d have to export/import sessions each time, that would be very painful. There is a replacement that allows local storage instead, having a look at the patch c file, it looks ok. https://jakub.kotrla.net/putty/

I discussed it again with the team, that is responsible for updating the other executable and for now the updates are infrequent enough, that we can afford to check manually the compatibility each time. Otherwise, that local storage fork looks promising, thanks for sharing!

Forwards compatibility is actually what you are asking for, a more difficult thing than backwards. That a new version will not introduce things that cause problems for older versions.
Unlikely that you would get a commitment from the developers that the configuration storage would remain the same. That would prevent improvements as cryptography state of the art changes. Likely a major rework of the storage schema would be in the change log, many people save and import this to mange their configuration, which has been very stable to date.
Also running older versions exposes you to bugs and security flaws. Software update procedures can always be more agile, especially to accommodate security critical networked software.
Absent a guarantee of forwards comparability, in this uncommon configuration you are responsible for testing that the old and new versions don't break each other. Have technical people use both and report any problems.  Maybe automate export and diff of the registry, and detect when anything changes.
Evaluate what it would take to change PuTTY to not use the registry. Apparently public libre patches exist, see https://jakub.kotrla.net/putty/  Presumably as a specific patch set it does what it advertises, if a little lagging behind upstream PuTTY. But think about if you want to trust different people with your remote access software.

Thank you for the detailed reply. You are right, forwards compatibility is quite improbable to guarantee for this use case. For the moment the updates are infrequent enough, that we can afford to check each time manually for compatibility. If this becomes too cumbersome, automating the check or looking at the fork you mentioned can be viable solutions. Automating the deployment is unfortunately not possible due to the security constraints set by the environment.
